# How can I make the pthread tasks executes in the correct order according to their priorities?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I'm trying to create 3 thread task with different priorities. The task will only wait or signal other thread tasks, and save the execution in char array to see that they executed as supposed.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void *pT1();
static void *pT2();
static void *pT3();

static void trigT3();
static void trigT2();

pthread_cond_t          gCondVar1;
pthread_cond_t          gCondVar2;
pthread_cond_t          gCondVar3;
pthread_cond_t          gFinish;
pthread_mutex_t         gLock1;
pthread_mutex_t         gLock2;
pthread_mutex_t         gLock3;
pthread_mutex_t         gLockF;

static char             savedExe[4];
static int              gPos = 0;
static bool             gSignalT2 = false;
static bool             gSignalT3 = false;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    struct sched_param  param1;
    struct sched_param  param2;
    struct sched_param  param3;

    pthread_attr_t      attr1;
    pthread_attr_t      attr2;
    pthread_attr_t      attr3;

    pthread_t           tid1;
    pthread_t           tid2;
    pthread_t           tid3;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr3);

    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr1, SCHED_FIFO);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr2, SCHED_FIFO);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr3, SCHED_FIFO);

    param1.sched_priority = 10;
    param2.sched_priority = 20;
    param3.sched_priority = 30;

    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr1, &param1);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr2, &param2);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr3, &param3);

    pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, pT1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid2, &attr2, pT2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid3, &attr3, pT3, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(savedExe); ++i) {
        printf("%c, ", savedExe[i]);
    }
    printf("\b\b\n");

    pthread_cond_signal(&gCondVar1);

    /*.
    .
    .
    .*/
    pthread_cond_wait(&gFinish, &gLockF);

    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid3, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(savedExe); ++i) {
        printf("%c, ", savedExe[i]);
    }
    printf("\b\b\n");

    return 0;
}

static void trigT3(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gLock3);
    pthread_cond_signal(&gCondVar3);
    gSignalT3 = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gLock3);
}

static void trigT2(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gLock2);
    pthread_cond_signal(&gCondVar2);
    gSignalT2 = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gLock2);
}

static void *pT1(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gLock1);
    pthread_cond_wait(&gCondVar1, &gLock1);
    trigT3();
    gPos++;
    savedExe[gPos] = '1';
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gLock1);

    pthread_cond_signal(&gFinish);

    return NULL;
}

static void *pT3(){
    //printf("T3\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gLock3);
    if(!gSignalT3){
        pthread_cond_wait(&gCondVar3, &gLock3);
        gSignalT3 = false;
    }
    trigT2();
    gPos++;
    savedExe[gPos] = '3';
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gLock3);
    return NULL;
}

static void *pT2(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gLock2);
    if(!gSignalT2){
        pthread_cond_wait(&gCondVar2, &gLock2);
        gSignalT3 = false;
    }
    gPos++;
    savedExe[gPos] = '2';
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gLock2);
    return NULL;
}
```

In the main, I create the 3 different tasks and assign them with different priorities. pT1 has the lowest priority = 10, pT2 = 20 and pT3 = 30.
pT1 starts the execution first and since its a lower priority and it triggers pT3, pT3 will start executing. pT3 will trigger pT2 but since pT2 is lower priority, pT3 will finish executing and then it will trigger pT2.

The output of this should be 3, 2, 1.
But what I get is 1, 2, 3, as if it does not take care to any priority at all and just executes the tasks in the given order.

Comment: Priorities do not set the order the threads are executing. The first thread might be already finished before the second one starts. If you want them to fully execute in a particular order, you should not make them threads at all. Or implement a proper synchronization, such that a subsequent thread is "released" only after the previous one is finished.

Comment: In fact, priorities do absolutely nothing at all if there are enough CPU cores available to run all of the threads at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Priority affects how much CPU time a thread gets when multiple threads want to use the CPU at once. It's not relevant here.

---

The problem is that you call `trig` too soon! You want T2 to run after T3, but you trigger T2 before T3 does its thing. Both end up trying to modify `savedExe` and `gPos` at the same time, which is bad. Both problems are avoided by properly ordering the statements.

```c
static void *pT3() {
    wait_for_trigger(&gLock3, &gCondVar3, &gSignalT3);
    savedExe[gPos++] = '3';
    trigger(&gLock2, &gCondVar2, &gSignalT2);
    return NULL;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MEhsoj57P) on Compiler Explorer

---

Note that you don't need so many mutexes and conv vars. You could use a single mutex and condvar for all signals.

```c
static void wait_for_trigger(bool *flag) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while (!*flag)
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

static void trigger(bool *flag) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   *flag = true;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/78dTr1EKK) on Compiler Explorer

You could even use a single variable for the different priority levels!

```c
static void wait_for_level(int a_prio_lvl) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while (prio_lvl > a_prio_lvl)
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

static void switch_to_level(int a_prio_lvl) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   prio_lvl = a_prio_lvl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9jq99ncnv) on Compiler Explorer

---

You have numerous other problems covered below. These are all fixed in this demo.

**Improper prototype**

```c
static void *pT1();
```

should be

```c
static void *pT1(void);
```

Empty parens in a declaration doesn't mean no arguments. You need to use `void` to mean that.

**Improper arguments**

```c
static void *pT1() { ... }
```

should be

```c
static void *pT1(void *arg) { ... }
```

`pthread_create` calls the function with a `void *` argument.

You can use `(void)arg` to silence the unused argument warning.

**Uninitialized mutexes**

```c
pthread_mutex_t gLock1;
```

should be

```c
pthread_mutex_t gLock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Mutex need to be initialized before they are used!

**Uninitialized cond vars**

```c
pthread_cond_t gCondVar1;
```

should be

```c
pthread_cond_t gCondVar1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Cond vars need to be initialized before they are used!

**Incorrect expectations from `pthread_cond_wait`**

```c
if (!gSignalT3){
   pthread_cond_wait(&gCondVar3, &gLock3);
}
```

should be

```c
while (!gSignalT3){
   pthread_cond_wait(&gCondVar3, &gLock3);
}
```

`pthread_cond_wait` can return *at any time*. To be clear, `pthread_cond_wait` can return even if `pthread_cond_signal` hasn't been used. So it must always be called in a loop that checks some external condition.

**Passing unlocked mutex to `pthread_cond_wait`**

```c
pthread_cond_wait(&gFinish, &gLockF);
```

This suffers from four problems we've already covered:

- Lack of initializing of `gFinish`
- Lack of initialization of `gLockF`
- Lack of a required loop
- Lack of an external condition

But that's not it.

`pthread_cond_wait` requires a locked mutex, but you are passing an unlocked mutex. It will return immediately with error `EINVAL`.

**Useless code**

This is again about

```c
pthread_cond_wait(&gFinish, &gLockF);
```

It's completely unneeded. `pthread_join` already waits for the thread to finish. So this serves no purpose.

---

Full final code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t  cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int prio_lvl = 3;

static int  gPos = 0;
static char savedExe[3];

static void wait_for_level(int a_prio_lvl) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while (prio_lvl > a_prio_lvl)
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

static void switch_to_level(int a_prio_lvl) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   prio_lvl = a_prio_lvl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
}

static void *pT1(void *arg) {
   (void)arg;
   wait_for_level(1);
   savedExe[gPos++] = '1';
   return NULL;
}

static void *pT2(void *arg) {
   (void)arg;
   wait_for_level(2);
   savedExe[gPos++] = '2';
   switch_to_level(1);
   return NULL;
}

static void *pT3(void *arg) {
   (void)arg;
   wait_for_level(3);
   savedExe[gPos++] = '3';
   switch_to_level(2);
   return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
   pthread_t tid1;
   pthread_t tid2;
   pthread_t tid3;

   pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, pT1, NULL);
   pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, pT2, NULL);
   pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, pT3, NULL);

   pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
   pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
   pthread_join(tid3, NULL);

   {
      const char *format = "%c";
      for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(savedExe); ++i) {
         printf(format, savedExe[i]);
         format = ", %c";
      }

      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes your code is giving the correct output, but you never set the priority for the threads, which is the main thing in my case. For example when pT1 (low priority) signals pT3 (higher priority), the signal should wake up higher-prio directly without task waits/yields processing

Comment: The last demo, the one with the switch_to_level is just hanging, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: There was a bug that was effecting both the second and third version. T3 would wake up either T1 or T2 ("randomly"). If it happened to wake up T2, everything was fine. But if it happened to wake up T1, the program would end up deadlocking. We want to wake up all threads so they can all check if the level is now suitable for them, so we want to use `pthread_cond_broadcast` instead of `pthread_cond_signal`. Fixed.

Comment: Yes your code is giving the correct output, but you never set the priority for the threads, which is the main thing in my case. For example when pT1 (low priority) signals pT3 (higher priority), the signal should wake up higher-prio directly without task waits/yields processing
ex.  param1.sched_priority = 50;
      param2.sched_priority = 70;
      param3.sched_priority = 90;
These priorites will assign each thread priority. Meaning, that pT3 has higher priority than the other, and so on.

Comment: You mentioned that I can use the same mutex (lock) and cond vars for all signals and threads!, would you tell the difference between using same mutex for different threads?  In which case will I need to use different locks (mutex)?

Comment: Adding cars to an empty road doesn't really add to traffic. But keep adding cars and you eventually get bad traffic. Same idea here. You could use independent locks and signals, which means fewer threads trying to lock each lock, and fewer threads woken on up a signal. But until you reach a certain level of "traffic", all that does is increase the amount of needed resources.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as i understood your requirements. You want to make priority based thread initiation and storing result in what so ever form.

You can achive this by making a simple priority queue of struct having the priority value and the ptherad variable to hold thread information.

only catch is that you need to make a custom priority queue in c over a structure of roughly of this kind

```
typedef struct prt_qu{
    uint8_t prty;
    pthread th;
} ptr_qu;
```

Upon execution you just need to enqueue all tasks in priority queue and make the main thread call these threads one by one. You can make main wait for current thread wait by just using `pthread_join()`.